# Cannot send push notifications via pushsharp on adhoc distribution

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, pushsharp

I'm using [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) to send iOS notifications to an application.

I've managed to make it work in a development environment following the example, but when I try to send them in a production environment I get the following error:

```
InnerException = {"No se pudo realizar una llamada a SSPI; consulte la excepción interna."
{"SSL Stream Failed to Authenticate as Client"}
```

Here's the code:

```
 var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, "path/to/file", "MyPassword", false);


        // Create a new broker
        var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker (config);

        // Wire up events
        apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) => {

            aggregateEx.Handle (ex => {

                // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
                if (ex is ApnsNotificationException) {
                    var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;

                    // Deal with the failed notification
                    var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                    var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;

                    Console.WriteLine ("Apple Notification Failed: ID={apnsNotification.Identifier}, Code={statusCode}");

                } else {
                    // Inner exception might hold more useful information like an ApnsConnectionException          
                    Console.WriteLine ("Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason : {ex.InnerException}");
                }

                // Mark it as handled
                return true;
            });
        };

        apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) => {
            Console.WriteLine ("Apple Notification Sent!");
        };

       // var i = JObject.FromObject(push);
        // Start the broker
        apnsBroker.Start ();

        apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
            {
                DeviceToken = "somedevicetokenthatiusetotest",

                Payload = JObject.Parse("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"My custom alert\",\"badge\":\"1\"}, \"date\": \"2016-06-07T01:38:00.541Z\"}"),
            });

        // Stop the broker, wait for it to finish  
        // This isn't done after every message, but after you're
        // done with the broker
        apnsBroker.Stop ();
```

I'm pretty sure that It has something to do with the certificates and how do I generate them. What I've done so far:

- Create a new distribution certificate
- Create a new APS production certificate
- Create an adhoc distribution provisioning profile
- Install all on my mac
- Archived the app using the distribution certificate code signing and the adhoc provisioning profile.
- Export it for adhoc distribution
- Install the app on an authorized device
- Exported a .p12 file from the certificate private key with a proper password.

Did someone experience issues with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've finally made it work by exporting *just the certificate* as a  .p12 file, and then using that file with PushSharp.